# Hide \author, \date, and \title when exporting to pdf with org-latex-export-to-pdf

Tags: org-mode, latex, pdf

I am very new to LaTeX and exporting org-mode files to pdf. When I run the command `org-latex-export-to-pdf` it adds a title, author name, and date to the top of the exported pdf. Looking at the generated LaTeX, I assume that comes from the lines:

```
\author{Ethan Skinner}
\date{\today}
\title{My Title}
```

How can I export a pdf without these properties? I have tried using both the
`VISIBLE-ONLY` and `BODY-ONLY` arguments to `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, but this didn't work for me

Comment: I think `#+OPTIONS: author:nil` will remove the author from exports, I'm almost sure the rest can be handled by options too, but I don't remember the syntax for it.

Comment: with the option it keeps the spacing though, I'd like to remove them completely...

Answer (score 32):

OK, thanks to @wvxvw putting me on the right track I figured it out.

You can get rid of the author and date with:

```
#+OPTIONS: author:nil date:nil
```

The Org Manual says that you can also toggle title with `title:nil` (`org-export-with-title`). However, this option didn't get rid of the title, and I couldn't find a variable or command `org-export-with-title`. However, from [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-07/msg01189.html) I found that I can get rid of the title simply by adding: `#+TITLE:` and not entering a title. This does add an extra line to my document, and it seems like it would make more sense to do it in the `#+OPTIONS`, but this will do.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently change that? So that you don't have to add it to every single org file/section you want to export? Thanks for helping!

Comment: title:nil is working for me under org-mode 9.1. :-)

Answer (score 14):

You can also redefine LaTeX's `\maketitle` to do nothing:

```
#+Title: Test title
#+Author: Test Author
#+Date: [2016-03-28 Mon]

#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand\maketitle{}

* hello
test text
```

Comment: the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Setting

```
#+OPTIONS: title:nil
```

on top of your file makes the `\maketitle` macro not to be inserted into the generated `.tex` file which makes neither the author, date or title to be shown in the resulting PDF file.